# How to mimic Google Keyboard's spacebar long-press functionality for switching keyboards?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

Google Keyboard lets you long-press the spacebar to switch keyboards in Android. I haven't turned anything up with a Google search but I'm certain there's a way to do this programmatically.

How can I bring up the input method picker?

Comment: I just tried long-pressing the space bar on my Nexus 6P and it didn't do anything special.

Comment: @dougstevenson Google Keyboard. I have the same device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use [showInputMethodPicker()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#showInputMethodPicker()):

```
private void onSpaceBarLongPress() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showInputMethodPicker();
}
```

Comment: The first statement produces an `Incompatible types` compilation error.

Comment: Added the appropriate cast

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for your swift response.

Comment: I know it's a late response but do you know how I can implement this in an `InputMethodService`? I don't see a built-in `onLongPress` event.

Comment: @shruggernaut - extend `KeyboardView` and override [onLongPress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#onLongPress(android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key))?