# Custom Android Keyboard - Key to Change "Keyboards"

Tags: android

I am creating my own Android Keyboard and I would like to add a key that when pressed it will open up the "Input Methods/Keyboards" dialog so I can change the keyboard.
Pretty much the same functionality the default keyboard has which if you hold "space" it will show a popup that allows you to change to other input method.

I haven't been able to find out if there is any predefined class doing such an action. If you can help me I will really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mimic Google Keyboard's spacebar long-press functionality for switching keyboards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376419/how-to-mimic-google-keyboards-spacebar-long-press-functionality-for-switching-k)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was searching for "Input Methods" key and haven't noticed this thread! This solves my problem, thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. Please select the "That solved my problem!" button (or whatever it says) so we know your question has been answered. Thanks. Cheers!